# Export EV Certificate from SafeNet to pfx

Tags: code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I am having a sectigo ev certificate that got to me via a usb stick. I can open the certificate with SafeNet and can import the certificate to my local store but only without private key. As I want to sign an electron app with it, I need a .pfx file with password. The old certificate was not an ev certificate and I could export it to a pfx and use it in my build. I could not find a way in the documentation to export the private key together with the public key, so I am stuck here now. From my google searches I also found out, that I am not supposed to export the private key and sign the software with the hardware token. But as I want to run this in a CI/CD in Azure and can not plug my USB Stick into the cloud, I am not really seeing a solution here.

Is there something I am missing? Maybe an option in SafeNet? Am I really not supposed to extract the private key?

Comment: Did you find any solution here?

Comment: No not really. After contacting the reseller they told me, that I bought a product that has the private key encrypted and therefore you can not extract it. This is a security measure that also means that I can not use this in the cloud because I have to sign with the usb stick in the pc. So as long as I don’t know where the USB port to the cloud is, I will not be able to sign. One could argue that you should disclose that very clearly on the productpage. And they also do not offer an EV cert that has the possibility to do that… that’s a way to waste 500 bucks and a bunch of time…

Comment: @modmoto - could you help maybe with the more basics? how to you protect the code when the stick is inside? I'm familiar with the pfx issue, but couldn't find any way for key....Thanks

Comment: I never did, to be fair, as it was clear that this approach is not usable for us. We are working from all over the world and no one wants to ping me to turn on my PC to sign an executable, including me xD

Comment: We sign on a local build machine, but one possible approach would be to rent a dedicated server from a provider that allows you to send in the USB token which they will then plug into the server. Also have a normal (non-EV) signing certificate as backup in case you lock yourself out of the token or if you forget to order a new one before it expired.

Comment: We actually do have a dedicated server but I was not aware that you could give them a USB stick to put into the actual server. We did not think of this solution as we ended up using a different vendor, but good to know that this is theoretically possible with rented machines.